# Exclusive locks on NetworkStream

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, ftp, stream

Is it possible to get an exclusive lock * on a stream object? In particular: `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream`.

*: By "lock" I mean preventing anyone with a reference to my stream object from reading/writing to it for as long as I still hold a reference to it as well.

I'm writing a stream decorator for my FTP library. It wraps a network stream and adds all sorts of FTP-specific commands. It looks a lot like this:

```
Public Class FtpStream
    Inherits Stream

    Private ReadOnly _networkStream As NetworkStream
    Private ReadOnly _streamReader As StreamReader
    Private ReadOnly _streamWriter As StreamWriter

    Friend Sub New(networkStream As NetworkStream)
        If networkStream Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("networkStream")
        End If
        _networkStream = networkStream
        _streamReader = New StreamReader(_networkStream, Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        _streamWriter = New StreamWriter(_networkStream, Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    End Sub

#Region "IO.Stream"

    ' Most calls to overridable members are delegated to _networkStream (Omitted for brevity).
    ' Read/Write calls throw InvalidOperation; users are expected to call FTP-specific methods.

#End Region

#Region "FTP-specific"

    Public Function NoOperation() As String
        _streamWriter.WriteLine("NOOP")
        _streamWriter.Flush()
        Return _streamReader.ReadLine()
    End Function

    Public Function User(userName As String) As String
        _streamWriter.WriteLine(String.Concat("USER ", userName))
        _streamWriter.Flush()
        Return _rea_streamReaderer.ReadLine()
    End Function

    Public Function Pass(password As String) As String
        _streamWriter.WriteLine(String.Concat("PASS ", password))
        _streamWriter.Flush()
        Return _streamReader.ReadLine()
    End Function

    Public Function PrintWorkingDirectory() As String
        _streamWriter.WriteLine("PWD")
        _streamWriter.Flush()
        Return _streamReader.ReadLine()
    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

Now that I have some basic (no pun intended, sorry C# folks) methods that I can use to talk to my FTP server, I need to start worrying about the current connection state. Have I logged in? Are we still negotiating options? Does this server speak UTF8? The list goes on.

This wouldn't be all that bad if I had an exclusive lock on `_networkStream`. But right now, anyone with a reference to the underlying stream object can do something that can later on break my whole program. Heck, I can't even ensure that the stream object hasn't been used before it is passed to my wrapper class.

Is it there any way to get some sort of exclusive lock on a stream object? Or perhaps I'm completely off-track?

**EDIT**

Right now I'm looking at `System.Threading.Monitor`. I'm too stupid to figure out how to use it though.

**EDIT**

I realized just now that this would probably mean I can't use `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter` anymore. But that's fine with me.

Comment: You'll need to explain by what scenario you expect other code to be able to use a **private** member of your class.  While you're at it, also best to explain why you write code to replace the .NET FtpWebRequest class.

Comment: Someone needs a reference to an instance of `NetworkStream` in order to create an instance of my wrapper class. That's how I expect other code to be able to read/write to it, and also the reason why I've declared the constructor as internal for the time being.

Comment: Well, perhaps you stopped too soon.  Just add the methods that create your own NetworkStream, just like FtpWebRequest does.

Comment: I didn't even realize that's something I can do. Problem solved!

Comment: By the way, this is mostly just a hobby project that should hopefully give me more insight into network programming. The FtpWebRequest class does a pretty good job hiding every little implementation detail, making it very difficult to learn something new.

Comment: Use the Reference Source to see what that code looks like.  Lots to learn from the framework code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Hans: in this particular situation, it is more appropriate to create a new instance of `NetworkStream` *inside* my decorator class. As opposed to creating an instance of the decorator to wrap a previously existing instance of `NetworkStream`.

Even though the original question remains, I'm going to mark this as resolved.